# Jframe Create a Close button that shuts down the application and a reset button to clear all text fields and run with new amounts

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

need to create a close button that shuts down the app and a reset to clear the fields and starts with new amounts .
my close button that I added does not do much on the code it just replicate the addInterest button function .

this is the frame

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 
import javax.swing.JButton; 
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JLabel; 
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 
import javax.swing.JPanel; 
import javax.swing.JScrollPane; 
import javax.swing.JTextArea; 
import javax.swing.JTextField; 

public class InvestmentFrame extends JFrame { 
  private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400; 
  private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 250; 
  private static final int AREA_ROWS = 10; 
  private static final int AREA_COLUMNS = 30; 
  private static final double DEFAULT_RATE = 5; 
  private static final double INITIAL_BALANCE = 1000; 
  private JLabel rateLabel; 
  private JTextField rateField; 
  private JButton btnInterest, btnExit; 
  private JTextArea resultArea; 
  private double balance; 



  public InvestmentFrame() { 
    balance = INITIAL_BALANCE; 
    resultArea = new JTextArea(AREA_ROWS, AREA_COLUMNS); 
    resultArea.setText(balance + "\n"); 
    resultArea.setEditable(false); 
    this.createTextField(); 
    this.createButton(); 
    this.createPanel(); 

    this.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT); 

  } 

  private void createTextField() { 
    rateLabel = new JLabel("Interest Rate: "); 
    final int FIELD_WIDTH = 10; 
    rateField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH); 
    rateField.setText("" + DEFAULT_RATE); 
  } 


  class AddInterestListener implements ActionListener { 
    @Override 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { 
      try { 
        double rate = Double.parseDouble(rateField.getText()); 
        if (rate < 0) { 
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(); 
        } 
        double interest = balance * rate / 100; 
        balance = balance + interest; 
        resultArea.append(balance + "\n"); 
      } catch (Exception exception) { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rate is a positive floating-point number.", 
                                      "Invalid rate value entered!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
      } 
    } 
  } 

  private class CloseListener implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      System.exit(0);

    }
  }

  private void createButton() { 
    btnInterest = new JButton("Add Interest"); 
    btnExit = new JButton("Close");

    ActionListener listener = new AddInterestListener(); 
    btnInterest.addActionListener(listener); 
    btnExit.addActionListener(listener); 
  } 

  private void createPanel() { 
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 
    panel.add(rateLabel); 
    panel.add(rateField); 
    panel.add(btnInterest); 
    panel.add(btnExit);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(resultArea); 
    panel.add(scrollPane); 
    this.add(panel); 
  }
}
```

And this is the Viewer

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 This program shows the growth of an investment.
 */
public class InvestmentViewer {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame frame = new InvestmentFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding close listener to your exit button. So it will not close the application.

```
ActionListener listener = new AddInterestListener(); 
btnInterest.addActionListener(listener); 
btnExit.addActionListener(listener);
```

The proper way:

```
btnExit.addActionListener(new CloseListener());
```

Comment: Just create another action listener and set all fields to default texts. There is not an easy way to do this.

Comment: `private class ResetListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == btnReset)
    resultArea.setText("");//reset the text in the resul area              rateField.setText("");//reset the interest in the rate field area aswell
        resultArea.setText(null);
         }
       }
     }**`   the code is not clearing the balance it clears the text but once i put new values it picks the last balance